# DataGridView Column Sort Numeric & Text value

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, sorting, datagridview

First of all... let me post here about my current situation.
I have a full project of others team in which dealing with DataGridView in .NET framework.

The code started from adding data using **Array** of **String** into every row as this code:

```
 data = New String() {number, budget, finDays}
 atable.Rows.Add(data)
```

There are 2 columns i want to sort:

1. **Budget column** : containing 2 types : numeric & text
2. **Finish Days column** : containing 1 types : numeric only

[image]

Thankfully i'm able to sort the numerical sorting using this code below:

```
If (e.Column.Index = 3) Then
            Try
                e.SortResult = Integer.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString).CompareTo(Integer.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString))

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            e.Handled = True
        End If
```

But i'm unable to sort the **Budget Column** using that code. What should I do then, any tips related to my current situation?

Comment: Try to add your `Columns` to `DataaTable` with its data type like `atable.Columns.Add("Budget Column", typeof(Int32));`

Comment: Is 'atable' a DataGridView or DataTable type?

Comment: The first column doesnt/cant contain *numbers* and text - it contains text and numerals (or all text) .  In order to sort the numerals by value (so 90 sorts lower than 15000) you'll pr4obably have to resort to a Natural String Sort

Comment: it is a DataGridView @TnTinMn,... and how to use natural sorting @Plutonix? what some adjustment do i need from the code above?